# Need html code of GridView within C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am having an aspx page with a user control in it. The usercontrol contains the GridView. At some place within this usercontrol i need html code of GridView.

Can anybody provide help on how i can get html code of GridView.

Thanks for sharing your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best source is to put a gridview into an aspx page and render it on the browser. On the browser, you can just right-click and View the source. You can copy paste and change accordingly.

Comment: Thanks buddy! But its somewhat complicated situation. Actually I have a GridView (gvStocks) having list of stock#. I am using devArchieve ToolTip control to show tooltip on each stock when mouse is hover. I need the tooltip to show notes associated with each stock. So I took another gridview (gvTemp) which is dynamically bounded depending upon stock#. I am trying to get the html source of this grid to provide it within the tool tip control. Thats why i need the html code.

Comment: I am trying with this code - System.IO.StringWriter oStringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter(); System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter oHtmlTextWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(oStringWriter); gvTemp.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter); but it gives me an error indicating it needs a form.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean html code? I'm assuming you don't want to view the HTML code via your browser --> View Source (or alternatively click on the control and view source), but do some sort of extraction/editing in HTML via your code in C#? Is that correct? If so you might be able to use JQuery - but it dpeends on your requirements.

EDIT: You can also try Firebug for Firefox since that can show you client side as code that's coming in from JavaScript, CSS, etc.

Comment: Thank you my friend. But please read my comment to the next answer.

Answer (score 1):

i hope i am not too late for answering your question, but your problem can be solved by overriding `VerifyRenderingInServerForm`

you just got to paste the following code in code behind

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{

}
```